# Generate a new UUID for each new file and send them afterwards to REL_SUCCESS

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I have an Apache NiFi Workflow, which takes some Files out of a FTP and puts them into a separate Folder, using ListFTP - FetchFTP and PutFile.

The problem is:

- Those Files, which were copied into the new Folder, need to be decoded, which will result in several other files. From File 1, I will generate around 300 other files and the original File will be deleted. (This is how it works and I cannot modify the behavior when it comes to the deletion of the file)
- Now, I want to have these Files decoded via a Python Script, called from an ExecuteScript Process in NiFi and eventually put the new Files into another Folder --> either via PutFile or PutHDFS (irrelevant at this point)

As far as I know, NiFi will execute it's entire Flow based on the UUID of each FlowFile. In my case, the original UUID of the FlowFile will no longer exist and 300 other files will be generated without an UUID, as these Files were never acknowledged by NiFi.

Is it possible to generate a new UUID for each of these new Files and send them afterwards to REL_SUCCESS?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `session.create(original)` where `original` is the incoming FlowFile, the returned FlowFile reference is a child of the original. It will have its own UUID and possibly the parent UUID as a separate attribute (although that might be up to the processor to do, such as SplitText).

Comment: Thank you Matt for your answer. If you could be so kind and help me out a little bit with understanding the flow, that would be great.
If I understand this correctly, I will retrieve my FF using get(). I will extract the UUID and the absolute path(because I need it for decoding), using getAttribute().
Now, what is not quite clear for me is how I will make the connection between the "original" FF and the newly generated files.
Should I initialize a new variable (let's say "FFD") and append the output of the create() function. Then return the FFD and call transfer(FFD, REL_SUCCESS)?